# What are unicoins useful for?

Tags: discussion

On serverfault, I see that there is a sidebar containing information about unicoins.  What is this all about and any other details?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's meta... who cares why the downvote?  Maybe because SE usually does something with unicorns on April Fool's day.

Answer (score 9):

An April Fools joke that's getting a bit old.

See [What are Stack Overflow unicoins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins) for more information.

Its release is based on your local timezone, so I in GMT+11 had this over 24 hours ago, and the rest of the world got it as midnight rolled around.

Comment: Old?! I thought it was brilliant. And quite a bit of work for just one day...